# What's the best way to recover data from corrupted iPhone 6s (iTunes not working/iCloud not used)

Tags: iphone, backup

What has happened... the timeline:

**29 Nov around 23:00** :   iPhone 6s full backup encrypted

**30 Nov around 07:00** :   iPhone 4s synched (backed-up automatically in the process / incremental backup)

**30 Nov around 18:30** :       iPhone 6s full backup encrypted

**Around 30 Nov 22:00**  :      Need to recover the iPhone 6s

29 Nov backup not visible on the backup list !

30 Nov 7:00 can be used but it recovers 4s backup onto 6s (included 6s app and some - not all - 6s data)

30 Nov 18:30 visible but when try to recover it says its corrupted operation failed (seems like my backup got mixed up)

I also have backup of iPhone 6s from 27 Sep, it works as well but when used I get again everything. I recovers iPhone 6s data and applications and iPhone 4s (applications)!

I can clean up the Sept 27 recovery but really need notes from Nov 29/30.
Is there a way to move them (backup files to a backup that works from 27 Sep)

If not are there tools to recover data?

I have found:

https://drfone.wondershare.com/ios-data-recovery.html

https://www.iphonebackupextractor.com/register/

Are there reliable/clean?

Appreciate any help!

Best regards,
Damian

PS. All backups are local iTunes based.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only need to get the notes from your backup, just download third party application to extract your notes from the Backup ( but if that is encrypted, most softwares ask to decrypt the backup first. So I assume 27th November backup is not encrypted)

After the extraction of Notes from backup, restore 27th November backup to iPhone and import those Notes from the PC (Which you are extracted from backup)

Import notes from PC : https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT205793

It is not quite possible to repair a corruped iTunes backup because mainly those are encrypted. So you best shot is what I described.

I think you have asked that whether these provided links applications are reliable and clean. I've used DrFone program personally and that wasn't quite satisfying. But that could be great for you since that has good ratings. Give a try to find out which program is the best for you to do your task.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried recovery software (3 different ones). None of them can handle the most recent backup :(

Comment: if none of third party softwares work properly, the best solution is just contact Apple Support team. They will tell you what you should do to make corrupted backup work again or solve your problem somehow. Thanks

Comment: I have also contacted Apple, they cannot help (what I expected). What is more annouying thou, is that I've been told that this is not a rare occurence when encrypted backup gets corrupted. For me when there is even a slightest possibility of something like that happening, the possibility of encrypting backup should not even be available! Ultimately I cannot recover my data, but all your suggestions were valid,. Thanks

Comment: Once I wanted to recover some images from my old backup which was corrupted. So I tried several softwares and all of them asked to decrypt the backup before extract it. They cannot simply decrypt it because iTunes is the only software knows which method or key it used to (combine with your password) encrypt that backup. I'm really sorry that I couldn't help you. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> 29 Nov backup not visible on the backup list !

Typically, iTunes/iOS update the existing backup, rather than starting a new backup from scratch. That's why the 29 Nov backup is missing, it was incrementally updated to be the 30 Nov backup.

I work on a tool called Decipher Backup Repair, which focuses on fixing these "corrupt or not compatible" (and other) restore error messages so you can restore using iTunes, even encrypted ones :) A lot of errors are repairable, even in encrypted backups.

There are a few instances where corrupt encrypted backup data is not recoverable, such as when the encryption keys are lost or incorrect ([this was a common problem in iOS 10.0-10.1.1 encrypted backups](https://deciphertools.com/blog/ios10-backup-encryption-bugs/)). Thankfully this was resolved in iOS 10.2 to at least prevent new instances of the problem arising. (If the problem already exists in an old backup, the incremental backups will keep building on the problem.)